# Doubly Linked List Java

Tags: java

I'm having some confusion about creating my DLList in java. My instructions say that my DLLNode  class should have links that point to the previous and next nodes. Do I need to create this under the data section or is it a method?

Thank you for your time

Comment: What is the data section in Java? That's generally an assembly term.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by data section... Have you learned single linked lists? Should be no different

Answer (score 3):

You can start declaring `DDList` like this:

```
public class DLList {
    private static class Node {
        int data;
        Node previous;
        Node next;
        Node(int d) { 
            data = d; 
        }
    }

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    // ...
 }
```

Some highlights:

- The `Node` class is an inner class of `DDList` and thus a member. So it is declared in the same section as the other members, e.g. fields. This is what you call "data section" I believe.
- You can declare `head` and `tail` before `Node`.
- Thanks to static, `Node` does not have a reference to the `DDList`. This saves (only) 4 bytes per `Node` but can avoid memory leaks if you pass unlinked `Nodes` outside `DDList`. It is also better style ihmo.
- Thanks to private, `Node` is not visible outside `DLList`. Since you need to access a class to access its fields, this is similar to setting `Node`'s fields as private. But it is more efficient because the compiler doesn't have to generate synthetic methods if you access `Node`'s fields in `DLList`.
- Consider making `data` final, so it cannot change.
- Consider making `DDList` generic. A cool exercise left to the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple DLL Node class I've been using this for the past few semesters on multiple projects.

I warn you though, simply copying code can violate the honor code of your institution.

```
private class Node {
    public Node prev, next;
    int digit;

    // initializes the new node's values
    public Node(Node prev, int digit) {
        this.prev = prev;
        this.digit = digit;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

When you need to add a node, you just need to remember to link the previous nodes 'next' field to the new node.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much, you just need to create two references that refer to itself and called them next and previous. so for example:

```
private class Node {
   int data; // assuming the data is an integer
   Node next; // this is the next reference.
   Node previous; // this is the previous reference

   Node(int data) {
     this.data = data;
   }
}
```